# Draw of one axis with Logarithmic Scale

Tags: plotting

I have a question. [image] As you can see figure, I could draw the z-axis logarithmically. However, this axis seems to descend to the negative side. Instead of range 0, 2, 4, can I draw this axis at range of 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000?

How can I solve this problem?

Murat

[image]

---

I want to draw the z-axis logarithmically. The used function is given by

```
sigmatotal=2.64405*10^13 f2^4-0.00658531 f2^3 f3+4.22499*10^-6 f2^3+5.28786*10^13 f2^2 f3^2-4.17641*10^-6 f2^2 f3+137116. f2^2-0.000527491 f2 f3^3-5.4387*10^-6 f2 f3^2+3.41195*10^-9 f2 f3-4.08533*10^-12 f2+2.64405*10^13 f3^4+7.22129*10^-6 f3^3+137116. f3^2-8.17067*10^-12 f3+0.05945
```

However, the used actual code to draw this grapgh in Mathematica is the following

```
Plot3D[sigmatotal, {f2, -0.005, 0.005}, {f3, -0.005, 0.005}, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 25, Mesh -> None, ScalingFunctions -> "Log10", AxesLabel -> {Style[Subscript[F, 2], Italic, Smaller, Blue], Style[Subscript[F, 3], Italic, Smaller, Blue], Style[z, Italic, Smaller, Blue]}]
```

As shown in the plotted graph, the z-axis is given as 0,5,10. But I want to draw the z-axis of this graph within the range of 0.01,0.1,1,10,100.

By the way, Dear Diaz- Navas,

Your suggested code did not work; ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log", None},

Murat

Comment: Please post actual code rather than an image.

Comment: Note that [`ScalingFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScalingFunctions.html) is red in your code which means that it is not recognized by `Plot3D` in your version of Mathematica. Hover the pointer over it to view the warning in the `Tooltip`.  `ScalingFunctions` was updated in v11. Presumably you are using an earlier version. Plot the `Log` of your function and explicitly specify the ticks for the z-axis.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Plot3D[Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 25, 
Mesh -> None, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log", None}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "f"}]
```

[image]

You can edit the ticks at your convenience and/or change what axis must be plotted in a log10 scale.

### Edit

By using the function provided:

```
Plot3D[sigmatotal, {f2, -0.005, 0.005}, {f3, -0.005, 0.005}, 
PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 25, Mesh -> None, 
ScalingFunctions -> {None, None, "Log"}, 
Ticks -> {Automatic, 
Automatic, Array[10^# &, 7, -2.]}, 
AxesLabel -> {Style[Subscript[F, 2], Italic, Smaller, Blue], 
Style[Subscript[F, 3], Italic, Smaller, Blue], 
Style[z, Italic, Smaller, Blue]}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Comment: Navas, The code you suggested worked in the new version MMA 11.2. Thank you for your effort. My problem is solved. Best Regards, Murat